# Convert string to query document type in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I have a string

```
var queryString = '{Occupation: occupation, Budget: budget , Interestedin: interest, Project: project}'
```

Where all the names are variable names, I want to pass this string into `db.User.find( QUERY )`. I have used JSON.parser to parse the same by doing

```
var object =. JSON.parse(queryString)
var result = await User.find(object)
```

But still not getting any results. When I try to print JSON.parse output on console, it prints nothing.

Comment: your queryString invalid json string

Answer (score 0):

With some initial sanitisation it is working:

```
 mongos> var queryString = '{ "Occupation": "occupation", "Budget": "budget" , "Interestedin": "interest" , "Project": "project" }'
 mongos> printjson(JSON.parse(queryString))
 {
    "Occupation" : "occupation",
    "Budget" : "budget",
    "Interestedin" : "interest",
    "Project" : "project"
 }
 mongos>
```